# During SQL query, convert the data displayed in row structure to column structure?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is such a query statement： `SELECT '159194340161331156','159194342669998394';`，It will return the query results in a behavior structure:

```sh
field name: 159194340161331156   159194342669998394
     value: 159194342669998394   159194342669998394
```

I hope it can be converted into the following results:

```sh
field name: id
     value: 159194340161331156
     value: 159194342669998394
```

Because this structure allows me to continue inline queries with the table.

Comment: You can use a VALUES table constructor to create a table on the fly.

Comment: *this structure allows me to continue inline queries with the table* "Inline queries" not exists. By the meaning - the constructionn which can be "inlined" may be subquery, CTE or view.

Comment: @Serg Create a temporary table at each query?

Comment: @Akina I actually want to optimize the in query. Is there a better way?

Comment: Post the task, not the way which you decide to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION` to return multiple rows.

```
SELECT '159194340161331156' AS id
UNION
SELECT '159194342669998394' AS id
```

Comment: Should this affect the performance of join table query?

Comment: What join query?

Comment: If there's a performance problem, you can put this into a temporary table and add an index.

Comment: The query criteria are different every time. Do you mean to create a temporary table while querying?

Comment: You create a temporary table and populate it with these IDs. Then you join that with the real table to complete your main query.

Comment: Because the query parameters are dynamic, this is an OLTP system query. You can't predict all the possibilities in advance.

Comment: The application can create the temporary table dynamically.